# How to Read a particular digit in input arguments to batch script

Tags: input, batch-file, digit

I have a batch script in which I have set a variable- "cpu-count" and its default value is set to 1. But when I call the batch script, the cpu-count is passed as an argument and its value can vary from 1-n. For example, I have to invoke the file as ' myscript.bat cpucount-4 ' or ' myscript.bat cpucount-7 '. I have to get this value of '4' or '7' in my script. Does anyone know how to read this value from the argument passed to batch script?

Answer (score 3):

You have several options to do that.

Getting from character 10 to end of string:

```
set value=%1
set value=%value:~9%
```

Removing from begining of value until dash:

```
set value=%1
set value=%value:*-=%
```

Separating value in two parts at dash, get second part:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%a in ("%1") do set value=%%a
```

I hope it helps...